# Invalid call of the object method in SOAP API

Tags: perl, soap, request

Perl code:

```
sub exec_cmd {

   use strict 'refs';

   my $self = shift @_;
   my $cmd  = shift @_;

   die 'Invalid call of the object method' unless ref $self;
   die 'Command not specified' unless $cmd;
   die 'Connection to SQL server not defined, use connect method first' unless $$self{'sql_pipe'};

   print { $$self{'sql_pipe'}; } $cmd . "\n";

   return 1;
}
```

My request to the API:

```
POST /xml HTTP/1.1

Content-Length: 452
TE: deflate,gzip;q=0.3
Connection: TE, close
Accept: text/xml
Accept: multipart/*
Accept: application/soap
Host: 127.0.0.1
User-Agent: SOAP
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:namesp13="SQL">
    <soap:Body>
        <namesp13:exec_cmd>MY SQL QUERY</namesp13:exec_cmd>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault>    <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Invalid call of the object method at SQL.pm     line 24.
</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

My question is, ¿how can I enter an argument in `exec_cmd` to be executed? I tried with the following XML but it doesn't work.

```
<namesp13:exec_cmd>MY SQL QUERY</namesp13:exec_cmd>
```

Comment: You don't appear to have defined `namesp13`

Comment: Thanks your fast response, ¿can you tell me a example with my 'demo' request?, thanks again!

Comment: You can define the namespace in the `exec_cmd` element or in any element that encloses it. It should look something like `<namesp13:exec_cmd xmlns:namesp13="http://www.example.org/interface">MY SQL QUERY</namesp13:exec_cmd>`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of telling how to encode a SOAP query unless you give us the details of the API. Normally the parameters to a request are expected in a subsidiary element inside the command. Like this for instance

```
<namesp13:exec_cmd xmlns:namesp13="http://www.example.org/interface">
  <namesp13:sql>MY SQL QUERY</namesp13:sql>
  <namesp13:param1>parameter one</namesp13:param1>
</namesp13:exec_cmd>
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but it don't work.

there is not way to declare "my $cmd = shift @_;" in the SOAP request?

Comment: @Jovenzuelo: My code is an *example* of the usual way things are done. As I said, I can't give you a proper answer unless you give details of the API you are using.